# Error when publishing Gem using API

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, publish

I am trying to publish a Ruby Gem to rubygem.org using the API whose documents have been provided [here](http://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-org-api/). I am getting an error when I try to publish a built gem file. I have tried both using a C# code and Postman (in case my code had some errors), but i get the following error

> RubyGems.org cannot process this gem. Please try rebuilding it and
>
> installing it locally to make sure it's valid.
>
> Error:
>
> tar is corrupt, name contains null byte

If I try to publish the very same gem using the command line

```
 gem push filename.gem
```

it gets published properly. Has anyone else used the API to publish gems, if so can they help me out.

My C# code is following

```
            var client = new WebClient();
            client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "--authorization key--");
            byte[] rawResponse = client.UploadFile("https://rubygems.org/api/v1/gems", Path.Combine(PATH, "tester-1.1.0.gem"));
```

If I am making a mistake in my code, a code snippet that works with the API will be highly appreciated as well. Thank You